# Is it possible to create 100+ tasker profiles from a spreadsheet?

Tags: sms, tasker

I'm looking to create multiple tasker profiles that trigger based upon DOB of a client and send a SMS wishing them a happy birthday.

That's easy enough, but replicating the same thing time after time over 100 times is pretty time consuming. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this externally to Tasker and then just importing them in? I have all the DOB and names in a spreadsheet so I'm hoping it could be simple.

Or, is there a way for Tasker to check DOB in your contacts folder and auto send an SMS if the date matches?

Answer (score 1):

Tasker imports/exports are usually in XML format. You can export your Excel file to XML, but it'll need a lot of formatting to become tasker-readable. The template is listed on the sidebar for [r/TaskerFiles/](http://www.reddit.com/r/TaskerFiles/).

If you have the DOB in the correct field in Contacts, you can trigger a task off your calendar (in Beginner Mode / Tasker version 4.5u1m for Android 4+ : Create a profile with State > App > Calendar Entry). You can select a specific calendar, and there's a calendar that just contains the birthdays of your contacts.

That's the trigger. After that, you'd need to retrieve the name of the contact (which should be contained in the calendar event title), [match it to a phone number](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/matching.html), and then disable the trigger so you aren't sending SMSs all day while it's someone's birthday.